# n-dimensional integration in R with limits as functions

Tags: c, r, integration, numerical

I'm aware of R packages such as `cubature` which are able to perform numerical integration for many integrals. However, in my situation the limits of integration are not integers, but functions of the other variables.

For instance, suppose I have

f(x, y) = 4*(x-y)*(1-y), where 0 < y < 1, y < x < 2

I want to compute a double integral (dy dx) over y < x < 2 for the range of x and 0 < y < 1 for the range of y. How would I do this in R (i.e. is this possible using the `pracma` package?)

I would be surprised if this isn't already implemented, but in that case, a link to an algorithm would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually quite easy if you just add (or rather multiply by) a term that sets the value of the function to zero at any (x,y)-tuple where (y >= x)

```
library(pracma)
fun <- function(x, y) 4*(x-y)*(1-y)*(y < x)
integral2(fun, 0, 2, 0, 1, reltol = 1e-10)
#=============
$Q
[1] 2.833363

$error
[1] 2.394377e-11
```

The integral function will not accept an infinite bound but since `y` is restricted to (0-1) and `x` is greater than `y`, then `x`'s lower bound must also be 0, which was why I put the limits in that way.

Comment: The condition should be ``x >= y`` but thanks for this answer

Comment: I actually posted the answer where I used `*(y < x)`. Then I looked at it and decided it was flipped and changed it , but now that I review the logic I do agree you are right and will revert.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the domain into three triangles (make a picture). Define these three triangles by giving their vertices in columns:

```
T1 <- cbind(c(0,0), c(1,0), c(1,1))
T2 <- cbind(c(1,0), c(2,0), c(1,1))
T3 <- cbind(c(1,1), c(2,1), c(2,0))
```

Then you can use the `SimplicialCubature` package. First define the union of the three triangles in an array:

```
Domain <- abind::abind(T1, T2, T3, along=3)
```

Define the integrand:

```
f <- function(xy) 4*(xy[1]-xy[2])*(1-xy[2])
```

Then:

```
library(SimplicialCubature)
> adaptIntegrateSimplex(f, Domain)
$integral
[1] 2.833333

$estAbsError
[1] 2.833333e-12

$functionEvaluations
[1] 96
```

The exact value of the integral is `17/6 = 2.833333....`. Thus the approximation we get is better than the one given by `pracma` in the other answer (not surprising: the integrand with the term `(y<x)` is not smooth).

---

For this example, we can even get something better with `SimplicialCubature`. The integrand is a polynomial: `f(x,y) = 4*x - 4*xy - 4*y + 4*y²`. The `SimplicialCubature` package has an exact method for polynomials.

```
> p <- definePoly(c(4,-4,-4,4), rbind(c(1,0),c(1,1),c(0,1),c(0,2)))
> printPoly(p)
Polynomial has 4 terms and 2 variables
4 * x[1]^1       (degree= 1 )
  -4 * x[1]^1 * x[2]^1       (degree= 2 )
  -4 * x[2]^1       (degree= 1 )
  + 4 * x[2]^2       (degree= 2 )
> integrateSimplexPolynomial(p, Domain)
$integral
[1] 2.833333

$functionEvaluations
[1] 9
```